# How to find a complete substring in another or in a variable

Tags: regex, string, batch-file, trim, findstr

I have to Install/Uninstall some products with batch scripts and also use log files to check if Installed or Uninstalled...

So if a product is installed correctly I have somewhere in my log file a line like this one (without quotes):

"SOMETEXT Windows Installer a installé le produit. SOMETEXT"

I would like to detect if (without quotes) "Windows Installer a installé le produit." is present in my file...

I tried a lot of things like :

- regex "^.*Windows[ ]Installer[ ]a[ ]install,[ ]le[ ]produit.*$" 
  (Didn't Match)
- trim each line and tried to findstr "WindowsInstallerainstall,leproduit"
  (Didn't work)

So I hope you'll give me one solution because, I'm looking for one for 3 weeks...

Thanks

Comment: `findstr /C:"Windows Installer a installé le produit." logFile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

A batch line like

```
findstr /i /L /c:"Windows Installer a installé le produit." "yourlogfilename"
```

should find that line, but without a relevant sample, it's not possible to test.

```
findstr /i /L /c:"Windows Installer a installé le produit." "yourlogfilename" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo NOT found) else (echo found)
```

should set `errorlevel` to zero if found, non-zero otherwise - and you should be able to extend the match-string to include *SOMETEXT* if required.

OR you may try a regex (within findstr's restricted implementation) by using

```
findstr /i /R /c:".*Windows Installer a install.le produit.*" "yourlogfilename" >nul
```